# QML error on exposing child properties

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a QML object defined as follows:

```
Item {
    property alias source: a.internalImage.source
    property alias text: a.internalText.text

    Column {
        id: a

        Image {
            id: internalImage
        }

        Text {
            id: internalText
            width: internalImage.width
        }
    }
}
```

This fails with: `Invalid alias target location: internalImage`.

However, if I do:

```
Column {
    property alias source: internalImage.source
    property alias text: internalText.text

    Image {
        id: internalImage
    }

    Text {
        id: internalText
        width: internalImage.width
    }
}
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As from the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdeclarativescope.html), the scope of a `Component` is:

> the union of the object ids within the component and the component's root element's properties

So, the outer element is not allowed to access to the `id`s contained in the inner element by means of a chain of `id`s.
On the other side, if you explicitly export a bunch of parameters by means of a set of variables, those values/references are freely available to the outer component.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve this issue by creating a simple property and a changeListener

```
Item {
    property string source: a.internalImage.source
    property string text: a.internalText.text

    onSourceChanged: a.internalImage.source = source
    onTextChanged: a.internalText.text
}
```

I hope this helps